# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40801) with this library (version 0x40805)

Tags: python, qt, anaconda

I have install Anaconda 2.0.1 on KDE desktop. When I run python and would see all modules installed, I have this message "Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40801) with this library (version 0x40805)",

Can I fix the problem if I unintall Qt library (version 0x40801)? 
How I do that?

Or if someone have another suggestion,please help me,

Thx very much

Comment: See this [anaconda issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/32).

Answer (score 0):

QT aggressively tries to find other QT installations on the system. It is likely finding the one installed by Linux. You likely can't remove this, as there are probably several programs that come with Linux that use QT, but is it possible to update it to the same version?

Comment: Okey, thank you for your answer, can you help me how to update at the same last version

Answer (score 0):

I find a way out of this question from qt website.

> **When starting Genymotion on Linux, why does an error message state that Qt library versions are incompatible?**
>
> Under Linux, when starting Genymotion, you may read the following
>   error message:
>
> ```
> [Genymotion] [Fatal] Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version XXXXXXX) with this library (version XXXXXXX)
> ```
>
> Indeed, Genymotion provides its own Qt library files. Those files may
>   be incompatible with the version of libraries that already exist on
>   your system. To solve this issue, you can remove Genymotion Qt library
>   files so that the application uses the ones of your system.
>
> To remove Genymotion Qt library files, in the Genymotion directory,
>   run the following command:
>
> ```
>  rm libQt*
> ```

you can try it